# Recursively printing all files in a folder up to a certain depth

Tags: java, file, recursion, directory

I'm looking to search all the file/folders in a given directory up to a certain depth. This is my code so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* 
 * Michael Woloski - Program Three
 * 
 * This program allows the user to enter a desired path
 * then the program will display every file or directory
 * within the specified path. The user will also enter a
 * desired depth, so if the path contains multiple 
 * directories, it will display the files/folders in the sub
 * directory
 */

public class MainClass {

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void fileListingMethod( File [] files, int depth )
{
    if( depth == 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for( File file : files )
        {
        if( file.isDirectory() )
            {
                System.out.printf( "Parent: %s\n", file.getParent() );
                System.out.printf( "    Directory:  %s\n", file.getName() );
                fileListingMethod( file.listFiles(), depth-- );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.printf( "        File:       %s\n", file.getName() );
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main( String [] args )
{
    System.out.printf("Please Enter a Desired Directory: ");
    String g_input = sc.nextLine();

    if( new File( g_input ).isDirectory() )
    {
        System.out.printf( "Please Enter Desired Depth: " );
        int depth = sc.nextInt();
        File [] file = new File( g_input ).listFiles();
        fileListingMethod( file, depth );
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.printf( "The path %s is not a valid entry. Exiting. ", g_input );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
  }
}
```

however, if the user inputs 3 as the depth it scans all the folder/files within the first three folders in the directory.

Essentially, Im looking to get the files/folders from one directory up to the desired depth.

Comment: `if the user inputs 3 as the depth it scans all the folder/files within the first three folders`. Depth would mean how many nested folders it would go down, not how many folder it would check.

Comment: Yes, for example I'm checking my downloads folder C:\Users\Name\Downloads and I have 4 folders within that directory, if I input 3, only 3 of the 4 folders actually get looped and when they do they show every file or sub folder within the folder and continue until the final file prints.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing depth in making the recursive call; you should just use depth-1 (giving the value you want without changing it).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, however isn't depth-- the same as depth-1 cause you are decrementing the variable one time each iteration?

Comment: But you want to pass the same value for all subdirectories of the same directory; changing depth won't do that.